# Why in MATLAB is realmax minus something still equal to realmax?

Tags: matlab, numerical-computing

In MATLAB, if I do `realmax - 1000000 == realmax` I get a logical 1 (true) as an answer. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a true result because the value of `1000000` (i.e. `1e6`) is much smaller than [the floating point relative accuracy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) of a [double precision variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) for values at or near the maximum limits. For example:

```
>> realmax-1e6==realmax  % Subtract 1 million

ans =
  logical

   1       % Still equal; not big enough to register a change

>> realmax-eps(realmax)==realmax  % Subtract the distance to the next largest value

ans =
  logical

   0       % Unequal; yeah, that's big enough to matter
```

In short, the distance between representable numbers at the maximum limit (i.e. `eps(realmax)`) is on the order of `10^292`. Subtracting a *much* smaller value of `1e6` gives a result that just gets rounded back to what it was before.

You can find more comprehensive explanations of dealing with floating point numbers [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738).